# Count the number of line in a string builder function

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Am using a following function in listener for posting data from JMeter test to influxDB. Please check the following method `PostMeasurement` at current it is posting data after each sampler triggered and the result is out.

`Metrics` is the `stringBuilder` class which hold the entire data line after line (please refer the sample result below), I want the `post method` to be called after reaching a value which can be set from user. For example 200,means when the metrics reached to it 200 line the post method will trigger and data will post to influxdb and new set of data should be pushed to the `Metrics` again starting from 0. This will repeat till my Test in the JMeter end.

I am trying to count the number of line but unable to do it,

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

try {

  Metrics = new StringBuilder();
  String status = "Failure";
  if (sampleResult.isSuccessful())
    status = "Success";
  if (sampleResult.getSampleLabel().startsWith("/"))
    Metrics.append("Requests")
  else
    Metrics.append("JMeter_Result")
  Metrics.append(",requestName=")
    .append(escapeValue(sampleResult.getSampleLabel()))
    .append(",httpstatuscode=")
    .append(sampleResult.getResponseCode())
    .append(",status=")
    .append(status)
    .append(",ScenarioID=")
    .append('${__groovy(vars.get("uniqueScenario_Id"),)}')
    .append(" responseTime=")
    .append(sampleResult.getTime())
    .append(",responsecode=")
    .append("\"${(sampleResult.getResponseCode())}\"")
    .append(",sentBytes=")
    .append(sampleResult.getSentBytes())
    .append(",receivedBytes=")
    .append(sampleResult.getBytesAsLong())
    .append(",responseMessage=")
    .append("\"${(sampleResult.getResponseMessage())}\"")
    .append(",samplecount=")
    .append(sampleResult.getSampleCount())
    .append(",errorCount=")
    .append(sampleResult.getErrorCount())
    .append(" ")
    .append(sampleResult.getTimeStamp())
    .append("000000");
  if (sampleResult.getSampleLabel().equals("UserIdleTime")) {} else {
    PostMeasurement(Metrics.toString());
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Error in Grafana Metrics Listener : " + e);
}
//Escape the string values before posting the data
String escapeValue(String val) {
  String responseValueForSpaceRemoval;
  responseValueForSpaceRemoval = removeWhiteSpaces(val);
  val = responseValueForSpaceRemoval.replaceAll(",", "\\\\,")
    .replaceAll(" ", "\\\\")
    .replaceAll("=", "\\\\=")
    .trim();
  return val;
}
static String removeWhiteSpaces(String input) {
  return input.replaceAll(~/\s/, '')
}

// Post the result to influxDB
void PostMeasurement(String Metrics) {
  def httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
  def httpPost = new HttpPost();
  httpPost.setURI(new URI(vars.get("InfluxDBAPI")));
  log.info(Metrics);
        //<want to build the logic here>
        // if(lineNumber < 200[for example]) {
                //httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(Metrics));
                //HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                //EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
        
        //}
        //else {
        // continue;
        //}  .
}
```

**result sampler:**

```
2023-03-24 19:30:32,557 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2023-03-24 19:30:32,558 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2023-03-24 19:30:32,558 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 01_Study_Creation 1-1
2023-03-24 19:30:34,781 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: JMeter_Result,requestName=T01[Study]_LaunchApplication,httpstatuscode=200,status=Success,ScenarioID=T_1 responseTime=2162,responsecode="200",sentBytes=3878,receivedBytes=109580,responseMessage="Number of samples in transaction : 2, number of failing samples : 0",samplecount=1,errorCount=0 1679666432559000000
2023-03-24 19:30:42,386 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: JMeter_Result,requestName=T02[Study]_LoginToApplication,httpstatuscode=200,status=Success,ScenarioID=T_1 responseTime=5485,responsecode="200",sentBytes=20964,receivedBytes=244704,responseMessage="Number of samples in transaction : 4, number of failing samples : 0",samplecount=1,errorCount=0 1679666434782000000
2023-03-24 19:30:42,386 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 01_Study_Creation 1-1
2023-03-24 19:30:42,386 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 01_Study_Creation 1-1
2023-03-24 19:30:42,387 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2023-03-24 19:30:42,387 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the use case and what is your objective from this ?

Comment: Glad that you asked, I want to send the payload which I explained in the logic when the condition met. Because currently I am writing after every sampler execution. This has performance issue which I want to avoid.

Comment: We had similar requirement, please refer the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Sample:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

try {

  Metrics = new StringBuilder();
  String status = "Failure";
  if (sampleResult.isSuccessful())
    status = "Success";
  if (sampleResult.getSampleLabel().startsWith("/"))
    Metrics.append("Requests")
  else
    Metrics.append("JMeter_Result")
  Metrics.append(",requestName=")
    .append(escapeValue(sampleResult.getSampleLabel()))
    .append(",httpstatuscode=")
    .append(sampleResult.getResponseCode())
    .append(",status=")
    .append(status)
    .append(",ScenarioID=")
    .append('${__groovy(vars.get("uniqueScenario_Id"),)}')
    .append(" responseTime=")
    .append(sampleResult.getTime())
    .append(",responsecode=")
    .append("\"${(sampleResult.getResponseCode())}\"")
    .append(",sentBytes=")
    .append(sampleResult.getSentBytes())
    .append(",receivedBytes=")
    .append(sampleResult.getBytesAsLong())
    .append(",responseMessage=")
    .append("\"${(sampleResult.getResponseMessage())}\"")
    .append(",samplecount=")
    .append(sampleResult.getSampleCount())
    .append(",errorCount=")
    .append(sampleResult.getErrorCount())
    .append(" ")
    .append(sampleResult.getTimeStamp())
    .append("000000");

  def MBody = (ArrayList < String > ) props.get("MBody");
  if (MBody == null)
    MBody = []
  MBody.add(Metrics)
  if (MBody.size() < 100) {  // this value can be anything according to your desire
    def NBody = [];
    props.put("MBody", NBody);
    PostMeasurement(MBody);
    } else {
    props.put("MBody", MBody)
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Error in Grafana Metrics Listener : " + e + "\n " + e.getStackTrace());
}

String escapeValue(String val) {
  String responseValueForSpaceRemoval;
  responseValueForSpaceRemoval = removeWhiteSpaces(val);
  val = responseValueForSpaceRemoval.replaceAll(",", "\\\\,")
    .replaceAll(" ", "\\\\")
    .replaceAll("=", "\\\\=")
    .replaceAll("\n", " ")
    .replaceAll("\r", " ")
    .replaceAll("\t", " ")
    .trim();
  return val;
}

static String removeWhiteSpaces(String input) {
  return input.replaceAll(~/\s/, '')
}

public void PostMeasurement(ArrayList < String > Body) {
  def httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
  def httpPost = new HttpPost();
  httpPost.setURI(new URI(vars.get("InfluxDBAPI")));
  String sBody = "";
  Body.each {
    sBody = sBody + it + "\n"
  };
  httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(sBody))
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
  EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of lines where? In the [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)? With your current implementation everything goes into one line without any line breaks.

If you want to "count lines" you need to **create** the lines first, like:

```
.append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
```

and then you will be able to count the lines somehow, the easiest is using [StringUtils.countMatches()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) function from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) project

[image]

You will also need ot refactor your code and save the Metrics object into a variable

```
vars.putObject('Metrics', Metrics)
```

and try read it from there instead of creating a new instance:

```
    Metrics = vars.getObject('Metrics') ?: new StringBuilder()
```

otherwise the data will be lost and you will be sending metrics only from the last iteration of the current virtual user

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

Given you should add some new lines to your `append` statements if you want this to return anything other than 1, but here is how you do it without 3rd party libs:

```
int countNewLines(CharSequence line) {
   String[] lines = line.toString().split("\n")
   return lines.length
}
```

Now the logic in doing this is somewhat questionable in your situation.  If you wanted to know if something got a 200 http status response (200 lines is not possible given the code you showed).  Just check the return value on the HTTP response.  No need re-parsing the text to count the lines.